# How do i build an Advertising System from scratch?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, programming-languages, ads

I’m going to make an advertising system from scratch and put it inside of my Ruby on Rails Web Application. What books do you recommend and subjects (Algorithms, SQL?) should I learn in order to make this happen, where does one start?

I want the system to take User Data and when businesses advertise, the Users will get recommended Ads based on their likes, dislikes and other data. The advertising will take place only in my web application and on my website. I believe I am looking to do something similar to Facebook Ad System (images) and Google Ad Words, how did they do it?

Thank you.

P.S. I have little experience in Rails, Ruby language,Computer Science and programming in general but i am learning fast and building my application easily.

Comment: You could start with research about "recommender systems". I'm not experienced with those kind of systems but it's a keyword for you to start with.

Comment: Did you ever did this at all @LearningRoR?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ilya Grigorik did an awesome writeup with lots of code samples on this subject. See http://www.igvita.com/2007/01/15/svd-recommendation-system-in-ruby/

If you mean books on Ruby and Rails, I can recommend:

[Programming Ruby (AKA "The Pickaxe")](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934356085)

[Agile Web Development with Rails](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934356549)

Those were the starting points of my Ruby career.

Comment: OK, this told me how to write it in Ruby but ill put a P.S. down. I am new to just about every subject and term used in that article, either way its a great start. Would you recommend any books? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I'm currently writing my bachelor thesis about recommender systems with location based social networks. For the basics of recommender systems have a look at these books which helped me a lot:
http://www.amazon.de/Recommender-Systems-Introduction-Dietmar-Jannach/dp/0521493366/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1300796937&sr=8-1

http://www.amazon.de/Recommender-Systems-Handbook-Paul-Kantor/dp/0387858199/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1300796937&sr=8-3

and if you speak german, this book gives a good survey:
http://www.amazon.de/Empfehlungssysteme-Grundlagen-Konzepte-Andr%C3%A9-Klahold/dp/3834805688/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1300796937&sr=8-2

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation on what to read, ill be taking a look at them in the near future.

Comment: your welcome, definitely read the Recommender systems - An Introduction, it's not so complicated and a good survey. If you have any questions, feel free to ask!